# Plotting and saving a plot in a loop after the entire loop is done

Tags: matlab, for-loop, save, plot

I need to keep updating a plot within a loop because I am doing a linear regression for each segment in space. I can do that just fine and display a correct plot. But however I don't seem to be able to save the final plot to file. My code looks something like:

```
for i = 1:slabs

    %.....SOME LOOPED RESULTS HERE, SHORTENED FOR BREVITY.....

    p = polyfit(collectCoord, collectTemp, 1);
    t2 = floor(min(collectCoord)) : 0.1 : ceil(max(collectCoord));
    y2 = polyval(p,t2);

    h = plot(collectCoord, collectTemp, 'o', t2, y2);
    xlabel('X-Coordinate')
    ylabel('Temperature')
    axis([-8 8 50 800])
    hold on     
end

filename = [folder 'Plot' num2str(stepCount) '.jpg'];
saveas(h, filename);
```

What exactly is it that I am doing wrong here, or is there a much better way of saving the plot?

Comment: Your call to "saveas" looks ok, what's going wrong? An error? Nothing saved?...

Comment: Can you post the resulting figure you are getting, because at first sight this looks OK to me. Just as an aesthetic aside: you might want to use a different image format (I'd recommend WMF/EMF if the figure is to be used in MS Office, PDF or EPS(C) when using LaTeX or PNG/GIF elsewhere). JPG will give you lots of artifacts which look terrible for graphs and texts (but it's the superior format for photographs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling saveas() on the handle to the line you just plotted.  You need to supply a figure handle:

```
f = figure();

do stuff;

saveas(f, 'file.jpg');
or
saveas(gcf(), 'file.jpg');
```